# Where to run my Kinesis Producer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I need to build a Kinesis Producer app that simply puts data into a Kinesis Stream. The app will need to connect to a remote host and maintain a TCP socket to which data will be pushed from the remote host. There is very little data transformation, so the producer application will be very simple... I know I could setup an EC2 instance for this, but if there's a better way I'd like to explore that.

Examples:

- You can build a producer on AWS Lambda, but since I have to maintain a long-running TCP connection, that wouldn't work.
- You can maintain a connection to a WebSocket with AWS IoT and invoke a Lambda function on each message, but my connection is just a standard TCP connection

**Question:** What other products in the AWS suite of products that I could use to build a producer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no suitable managed options, here.  If your task is to...

- originate and maintain a persistent TCP connection to a third-party remote device that you don't control,
- consume wherever payload comes down the pipe,
- process/transform it, and
- feed it to code that serves as a Kinesis producer

...then you need a server, because there is not a service that does all of these things.  EC2 is the product you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The Producer code typically runs on the *thing* that is the source of the information you wish to capture.

For example:

- When capturing network events, the Producer should be the networking equipment that is monitoring traffic.
- When capturing retail purchases, the Producer is the system processing the transactions.
- When capturing earth tremors, the Producer is the equipment that is monitoring vibrations.

In your case, the *remote host* should be the Producer, which sends the data to Kinesis. Rather than having the remote host push data to a Lambda function, simply have the remote host push directly to Kinesis.

**Update**

You mention [Kinesis Agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html):

> Kinesis Agent is a stand-alone Java software application that offers an easy way to collect and send data to Kinesis Firehose.

If you are using *Amazon Kinesis Firehose*, then the **Kinesis Agent can be your Producer**. It sends the data to the Firehose. **Or, you can write your own Producer for Firehose.**

From [Writing to a Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream Using the AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-sdk.html):

> You can use the Kinesis Firehose API to send data to a Kinesis Firehose delivery stream using the AWS SDK for Java, .NET, Node.js, Python, or Ruby.

If you are using *Amazon Kinesis Streams*, you will need to **write your own Producer**. From [Producers for Amazon Kinesis Streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/amazon-kinesis-producers.html):

> A *producer* puts data records into Kinesis streams. For example, a web server sending log data to an Kinesis stream is a producer

So, a *Producer* is just the term applied to whatever sends the data *into* Kinesis, and it is retrieved by a *Consumer*.

Comment: No, that's not true. What you described is where the Kinesis agent should run. The remote host I described is a third-party.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

1. You may be able to use IoT with a [kinesis action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/kinesis-rule.html) for your remote host to push into a kinesis stream. In this case your remote app would be a device that talks directly to the AWS IoT infrastructure. You'd then setup a rule to forward all of the messages to a kinesis stream for processing. See https://aws.amazon.com/iot-platform/how-it-works/.

   A benefit of this is that you no longer have to host a producer app anywhere. But you would need to be able to modify the app running on the remote host.
2. You don't have to use the [Kinesis Producer Library (KPL)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-producers-with-kpl.html), your data source could simply make repeated calls to [PutRecord](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html) or [PutRecords](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html). Again this would require modifications to the remote app.
3. Or as you know, you could run your [KPL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-producers-with-kpl.html) app on an EC2. Talk to it over the network. This may give you more control over how the thing runs and would require less modifications to the remote app. But you now have a greater dev ops burden.